# Creating table with scroll down

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table where each row has a fixed height but when a particular height is reached a scroll bar appears.

The code for the table is:

```
<div style="postion: relative; left: 100px; height: 100px; width: 450px; overflow-y: auto">

    <table id="dataTable" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; height: 100px; width: 400px">
        <tr>
            <th>Data Source </th>
            <th>File Type </th>
            <th>FIles</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EDI DATA </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>ALL </option>
                    <option>CSV</option>
                    <option>xls </option>
                    <option>sap</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>EDI_Aug.csv</li>
                    <li>EDI_Aug.xls </li>
                    <li>EDI_Aug.xls </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>RECEIPT DATA </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>CSV</option>
                    <option>xls </option>
                    <option>sap</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>RECEIPT_Aug.csv</li>
                    <li>RECEIPT_Aug.xls </li>
                    <li>RECEIPT_Aug.xls </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CARRIER DATA </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>CSV</option>
                    <option>xls </option>
                    <option>sap</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>CARRIER_Aug.csv</li>
                    <li>CARRIER_Aug.xls </li>
                    <li>CARRIER_Aug.xls </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But the height of the table keeps on increasing as I keep adding rows. I want the height of the table to be fixed and a scroll bar appears when the data added exceeds the table height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why does the table have position absolute?

If you remove that, then your code works.

So the code would look like this:

```
<div style= "postion:relative;left:100px;height:100px;width:450px;overflow-y:auto;">
  <table id ="dataTable" style = "left:100px;height:100px;width:400px">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

You can actually use the position absolute in the table also if you need to have it.

```
<div style= "position:relative;left:100px;height:100px;width:450px;overflow-y:auto;">
  <table id ="dataTable" style = "left:100px;height:100px;width:400px">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

You just had a typo on the outer div `postion:relative;` which lead to your problem.

Setting the outer div's position to relative makes the absolutely position table inside of it base its position and height on the outer div, which has a fixed height, rather than on some other div or in the "worst" case the body. Without the outer, relatively positioned div, the table inside will always calculate its dimensions and position based on some other outer element and so can't figure out where it should scroll and where not.

Comment: it worked but why with position:absolute is the probelm

Answer (score 1):

I've added `overflow-y`  to `scroll` in the `div` tag. `Scroll` means that...

> ...the content is clipped and a scrolling mechanism is provided

Is that what you wanted?..

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 450px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.dataTable {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px
}

table {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="dataTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Data Source</th>
      <th>File Type</th>
      <th>FIles</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>EDI DATA</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>ALL</option>
          <option>CSV</option>
          <option>xls</option>
          <option>sap</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>EDI_Aug.csv</li>
          <li>EDI_Aug.xls</li>
          <li>EDI_Aug.xls</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RECEIPT DATA</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>CSV</option>
          <option>xls</option>
          <option>sap</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>RECEIPT_Aug.csv</li>
          <li>RECEIPT_Aug.xls</li>
          <li>RECEIPT_Aug.xls</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CARRIER DATA</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>CSV</option>
          <option>xls</option>
          <option>sap</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>CARRIER_Aug.csv</li>
          <li>CARRIER_Aug.xls</li>
          <li>CARRIER_Aug.xls</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

(i think you want to create something like this)

**Scroll-bars and overflow, overflow property**

*Default value:* `visible` meaning it will keep growing when adding content.
*Other value*:

- `hidden` when the new content overflows your element it will be
  (part) invisible,
- `scroll` scroll-bars will be visible, not matter if there is content
  overflowing your element.
- `auto` is there is content overflowing your element there we be a scroll-bar to scroll

overflow can only take 1 value if you want the specify witch axis you can use overflow-x / overflow-y property! beware if you need support for IE, IE < 7 does not support *-x* or *-y*! IE8 uses a prefix `(ms-)`.

```css
  /*action*/
  div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  /*style*/
  table {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(241, 0, 241, 0.3);
  }
  tr {
    background-color: rgba(241, 241, 0, 0.3);
  }
  /*webkit style*/
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
  }
  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(237, 28, 36, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(237, 28, 36, 0.4);
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>my big row</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```